# Website speed issues

Tags: wordpress, page-speed

I am developing a website however i have noticed speed issues, i am not sure whether is due to the location of the server.

I am not a guru when it comes to performance or speed issues, but according to a website speed test it seems that it takes quite a long time to connect to the website.

[Speed Test Results](https://browsermob.com/free-website-performance-test/8d433b1a52fe42979a0e269f0237d98f)

Can someone suggest something or give me some tips, the website address is http://www.n1bar.com

Answer (score 2):

I just did an analysis on tools.pingdom.com, results here: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/Hyu8qrcXJ/n1bar.com

From this, I gather (the yellow bar) that 1.5 seconds are spent for the user to wait for the server to send the starting data. You also have 128 requested objects, which is ridiculous. The next thing I see is a large number of decent-sized blue bars, which indicates the server is actively sending data to the user.

Looking at the actual data, it seems most of these requests are for `/plugins/*` which indicates you have a large number of plugins enabled. Try disabling those that you don't need.

Next, if you still have issues with speed after completing the changes from above, I recommend you look into a CDN system, which is optimized for sending content to locations through accelerated tunnels. This includes switching web hosts.

You may also benefit very much from server-side caching of static resources like images and stylesheets.

http://www.cloudflare.com is a CDN and caching service and may help, and it's free. You don't need to get a new web host if you use this.

If you still have any issues, don't hesitate to update your post or comment below.

Comment: I played around with .htacess and reconfigured my cache plugin and optimized some graphics and disabled some plugins and the load speed droped to almost 1sec, but the time which i performed the speed test could also have an impact since its now almost 06:00 GMT and most of the world is sleeping http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/uOKAm38Mv/n1bar.com

Comment: Alright, that's a major improvement. The next thing I have to say is this: 111 requests still, many are for JS/jQuery. Official suggestions by Pingdom: `Combine external CSS, Combine external JavaScript, Parallelize downloads across hostnames`. Would it be possible to further compress your images further? Second suggestion is to try CloudFlare, the content-optimizing CDN. They automatically compress JS and images and such.

Comment: I downloaded your homepage and uploaded to one of our servers and ran it both through CloudFlare and not. With it, it shaved off 1.92 seconds. It's deleted now though; no need for it.

Comment: I tried using smush.it plugin for wordpress to compress all images to a maxium without lossing quality but seems yahoo stoped the service temporarily until further notice.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good plugin to minify your CSS, JS, and HTML http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/

Also look for common jQuery on http://www.cdnjs.com which is a free CDN for common jQuery files that you can load from.

Answer (score 1):

A great, easy way to increase your page speed is to stick your site on [CloudFlare](http://www.cloudflare.com/).

It sits at the DNS level of your site and automatically serves all your static assets from a CDN, speeding up their delivery and saving you bandwidth - among many other features. It's free too!

Answer (score 1):

"This is a good plugin to minify your CSS, JS, and HTML http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/"

Just a quick note that you don't want to turn on minify options at both CloudFlare and W3TC,if using both. You would really just want to choose one or the other. Other than that, there are no conflicts with W3TC.